# Understanding Django localization in templates

Tags: python, django, localization

I am trying to use two languages in my website, my native, and an english one. I followed the django documentation, from where I copied the code. I have the locale folders and files set up.

When I open the site, it already sets the default language to Slovene, which should be English instead, and I don't know why. The `main.html` looks like this when I open the site:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html"
  xmlns:height="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  lang="sl" >
```

If I understand correctly, the `lang="sl"` should be `lang="en"`, and I do not know why it defaults to Slovene. Even when I use the form, it shows me both choices (English and Slovene), but when I select English, and click Go, it just refreshes the page, but doesn't change the language. The current language (Slovene) still stays selected, so I'm guessing that somewhere the correct language doesn't get selected.

I'm also confused as to why it doesn't default to English when I start the server. Can anyone provide some insight or point me in the right direction?

**settings.py**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Ljubljana'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale"),
]

ugettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
    ('sl', ugettext('Slovenian')),
)
```

**main.html**

```
{% load i18n staticfiles bootstrap3 %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}{% get_current_language_bidi as LANGUAGE_BIDI %}
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html"
      xmlns:height="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|default:"en-us" }}" {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}dir="rtl"{% endif %}>
...
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
<select name="language">
    {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
    {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
    {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
        <option value="{{ lang.0 }}" {% if lang.0 == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
            {{ lang.1 }} ({{ lang.0 }})
        </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

**project/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^l10n/', JavaScriptCatalog, js_info_dict),
    url(r'^$', index, name="index"),
]
```

**site/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.views.i18n import JavaScriptCatalog
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out why it refused to switch the language correctly. In the user model, I had already defined the language, and it was set to my native language, instead of the browser default.

When I changed the language to the browser default, the localization worked correctly. Not sure how Django checks for localization settings, but I just assumed it looks at the cookie first, and then the database. Guess I was wrong.